# npm auto add slash after username when proxy be set

Tags: node.js

I treid the following command to set proxy of npm:

`npm config set proxy=http://username:password@server:port`

Check the npm configuration and found npm auto add a slash after username.

```
C:\Users\username>npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.6.0 node/v8.9.4 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\username\.npmrc
msvs_version = "2015"
proxy = "http://username/:password@server:port/"
registry = "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Users\username
; HOME = C:\Users\username
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

And get the following error after trying to install vue:

```
C:\Users\username>npm install vue 
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npm.taobao.org/vue failed, reason:
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND username username:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\z00350820\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-15T13_21_46_283Z-debug.log
```

I also tried to set npm_config_proxy in envionment variables,but failed again.

Answer (score 2):

I observed the same behavior with a password containing a question mark. 
If your username or password contains special characters, you may have to [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) them.

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/532530)

Comment: Bravo.  This was the issue for a team member.  We noticed the extra slash was not in the environment ENV variable but was added to the npm config as described above.  We could not update it with npm set proxy .... changing the password to use an exclamation ! instead of a question mark ? worked.  The added slash was removed in the npm config and npm install began working

Comment: Bless your soul kind stranger